# Alternative for GROUP_CONCAT in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, filemaker, group-concat

Can someone please let me know how to change my query so it does not use `GROUP_CONCAT`.
The query works great for `MYSQL` and PHP but I need the same query to be run in `Filemaker Pro`, but Filemaker does not support GROUP CONCAT.

```
SELECT sqlvalue
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(stat_number = 693, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED) AS S693,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(stat_number = 698, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED) AS S698,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(stat_number = 2010, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED) AS S2010,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(stat_number = 2020, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED) AS S2020,
IFNULL(CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(stat_number = 693, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED),0) +
IFNULL(CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(stat_number = 698, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED),0) +
IFNULL(CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(stat_number = 2010, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED),0) +
IFNULL(CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(stat_number = 2020, sqlvalue, NULL)) AS UNSIGNED),0) + AS STOTAL
FROM statsvalue
WHERE sqldate > ’01-07-2013′
ORDER BY sqldate ASC
GROUP By sqldate
```

field `stat_number` is a code given to the records being entered, `sqlvalue` is a numerical value and `sqldate` is a date.

The above query takes the values for those `stat_number` and adds them up together and groups the total by `sqldate field`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but you don't need `GROUP_CONCAT()` in this particular case (doing conditional aggregation).

Therefore IMHO you can go ahead and change `GROUP_CONCAT()` with `MAX()` for example, which would likely make more sense, at least for reading the query.

I don't know Filemaker but you might also consider to change

1. `IF()` to `CASE END`
2. `IFNULL()` to `COALESCE()`

Besides that your query has a few other problems:

1. Even though MySQL allows you to you shouldn't be using `sqlvalue` column in `SELECT` clause without an aggregation function being applied to it to being a part of group by. It just doesn't make sense and other major RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres) don't allow it. **You've most likely meant to use `sqldate` instead.**
2. Even if you put `sqlvalue` in `SELECT` there should be a comma used right after the column name
3. There is an extra `+` right before `AS STOTAL`
4. You might need to use proper quotes instead of smart-quotes when using date string literals
5. You better use disambiguated date literals (instead of '01-07-2013' you should use either '2013-07-01' or '2013-01-07' depending on whichever you meant)
6. `ORDER BY` should go after `GROUP BY`

That being said your query might look like

```
SELECT sqldate,
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 693  THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED) AS S693,
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 698  THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED) AS S698,
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 2010 THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED) AS S2010,
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 2020 THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED) AS S2020,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 693  THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED), 0) +
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 698  THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED), 0) +
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 2010 THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED), 0) +
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 2020 THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED), 0) AS STOTAL
  FROM statsvalue
 WHERE sqldate > '2013-01-07'
 GROUP BY sqldate
 ORDER BY sqldate
```

or using inline view like this

```
SELECT sqldate, S693, S698, S2010, S2020,
       COALESCE(S693,  0) + 
       COALESCE(S698,  0) + 
       COALESCE(S2010, 0) + 
       COALESCE(S2020, 0) AS STOTAL
  FROM
(
  SELECT sqldate
         CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 693  THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED) AS S693,
         CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 698  THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED) AS S698,
         CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 2010 THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED) AS S2010,
         CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN stat_number = 2020 THEN sqlvalue END) AS UNSIGNED) AS S2020
    FROM statsvalue
   WHERE sqldate > '2013-01-07'
   GROUP BY sqldate
) q
  ORDER BY sqldate
```